# How to run Netbeans in Output Window?

Tags: php, netbeans

I am currently learning PHP but when I try to run the codes, It's opening a browser and it annoys me cause I cannot follow the course I am taking, I got these codes to display

```
function __construct($tempFirst="",  $tempLast="", $tempYear="") {
    echo "Person Constructor \n".PHP_EOL;
    $this->firstName = $tempFirst;
    $this->lastName = $tempLast;
    $this->yearBorn = $tempYear;
}
```

but on other browser the next line is not functioning, and on my OUTPUT windows is blank? please help me run it only in Output window, I want the result only in output window and not open a window when I run, the course I follow only displays output on Output window?

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to show PHP's project output in Netbeans output window. Perhaps you can do this,

Click on **Tools** -> **Options** and in **General** tab choose Web Browser drop down menu and select **Embedded Webkit Web Browser**. Now run your PHP project and this will open the output inside the NetBeans itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think netbeans do not have such a feature. You need to open a web browser to display the results